# Install active sync or equivalent on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-mobile, activesync

How can I install Active Sync on Windows 7?  I can't seem to figure out how... Microsoft says that I need Windows XP SP2 or earlier...

I'm trying to connect a Windows Mobile 5 phone.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried ActiveSync installed in Windows 7's XP Mode? (You may have to disable the XP firewall since it's SP3)

Comment: I don't have XP Mode.  If I had an XP ISO I could run VMWare... And use the key from my old computer...

Comment: Darned Home versions! ;)

Comment: so... what do I do?

Answer (score 1):

I believe *Windows 7* uses *Sync Center* instead, found in the *Control Panel*.

Comment: Yes, but how can I get that to interact with the SDK used to make apps for for Windows mobile 5?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that you can't do this, but the best you can try is to:

1. Right Click the setup.msi and select Properties
2. Select the Compatibility tab
3. Check box Run in Compatibility Mode and select Windows XP SP2 from the dropdown
4. Install

If you succeed in the installation, go to the Program Files/Microsoft/Activesync folder, find the main .exe and follow steps 1-3 above.

You might be better off installing XP in a Virtualbox and giving the VM access to the USB device that represents your phone, and syncing that way.  Or upgrading to a new phone :)

Comment: I don't have Windows XP SP2 under compatibility

Comment: What version W7 is this - do you have any XP entries listed?

Comment: Windows 7 home premium 64-bit.  No. No XP entries listed.